# How to have the number of 2 weeks between two dates?

Tags: python-3.x, date

I would like to know an efficient way to have the number of semi-month between dates.

I have this, code, it work, but I'm sure it could be enhanced ?

```
import math
import datetime

start_date = datetime.date(2021, 3, 15)

end_date = datetime.date(2022, 5, 30)

delta = end_date - start_date
print(delta.days)

delta = str(delta)
delta = delta[:-13]
delta = int(delta)

nb = int(math.ceil(delta/15))
print(nb)
```

Output :

```
441
30
```

Any ideas how to make this code more efficient ? I'm not sure this is th best way to do that.

Comment: What "inefficiencies" do you think need to be removed?

Comment: I don't know, I think this code could be improved in term of readibility and lines of code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can avoid `delta` entirely:

```
nb = int(math.ceil((end_date - start_date).days/15))
```

Note that, for *very* long ranges, this may be slightly off (since not all months are 30 days); it depends on exactly what you mean by "semi-month".

Comment: I mean 15 days :)